# how to solve syntax error in procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i am executing a procedure in mysql, procedure is-

```
delimiter $$
create procedure getFacility (in id int, out MyFacility VARCHAR(200))
begin
    select Facility into MyFacility 
        from facilities 
        where FacilityID = id ;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

and it is giving error below-

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end $$
delimiter' at line 1
(0 ms taken)
```

how to solve this error?

Thanks,
Yugal

Comment: Are you executing the query against MySql directly? or are you using a application connector like jdbc?

Comment: Try changing your delimiter to some other single character like `|` instead of `$$`

Comment: i am executing query against MySql directly. i changed delimeter to | insteed of $$, but now also it is giving error.now what to do? please suggest me.

Comment: i have put "END$$" but it is giving same error. Am i missing somthing?

Comment: Is there any other code that is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is because of the space between `END` and `$$`. 
Try `END$$` and it should compile properly.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: @Shooter - Did this help you resolve your issue? In comment you have mentioned saying `END$$` gives you same error?

Comment: i put DELIMETER $$; on the top and END; $$ DELEMETER; $$ at the end of procedure, now it is working. Thanks  -

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue... my solution was to just remove the delimiter operator call on line one, and remove the delimiter after 'END'... it seems JDBC just doesn't like that operator.

it would also be really nice if MYSQL gave some more precision on syntax errors.